# Singly Linked List nullpointerexception

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that removes all instances of a value from a singly linked list, but I'm having some trouble. I'm receiving a nullpointerexception on line 8 of this code:

```
public void remove (int value)
{
    IntegerNode temp=head;
    while (temp !=null)
    {
        if (temp.value == value)
        {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            count--;
        }
        temp=temp.next;
    }
}
```

Not certain what it is I'm doing that's bringing up this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read it, you want to remove temp from your list if temp.value equals value. However, your code has a few errors:

1. your code tries to remove temp.next instead of temp.
2. When temp.value equals value in the last element (where temp.next == null), the line temp.next = temp.next.next will trigger your NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `temp.next` is not `null` in

```
 temp.next.next;
```

It is safer to use as follows

```
 public void remove (int value){
  IntegerNode temp=head;
  while (temp !=null){
    if (temp.value == value){
       if(temp.next!=null){
          temp.next = temp.next.next;
          count--;
        }          
      }
    temp=temp.next;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fail in the last iteration:

> temp.next = temp.next.next;

For the last node, `temp.next` will be `null` as a result `temp.next.next` will throw NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition a bit cause the error might be coming when temp->next is null and you do temp->next->next.

```
if (temp.value == value)
        {
        if(temp.next != null)
            {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            }
            count--;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to remove temp.next instead of temp.

```
public  void removeAll(int element){
    Node node = head;
    Node prev = null;
    while (node != null){
        if(node.key == element){
            if(node == head)
                head = node.next;
            else
                prev.next = node.next;
        }
        else
            prev = node;
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```